# JavaScript Join Identical Adjacent Elements in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, element

Input:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']
```

Desired output:

```
['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd', 'ee']
```

Is this possible?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that my previous attempt (for another example) failed, and I cannot figure out why:

```
let newArr = []
let last
let current
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    last = last || isCurrencyArr[i]
    current = isCurrencyArr[i]
    let str = ''
    if (last === current) {
        str += arr[i]
    } else {
        newArr.push(str)
        str = ''
    }
    last = isCurrencyArr[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example has a few hiccups. It redeclares `str` inside each iteration, therefore it only ever pushes empty strings. Also, it pushes the previous string when it comes across a *new* item, but it doesn't account for scenarios where the last items are the same, as in your example with the letter `e`.

---

**If you're joining alike elements together, regardless of position...**

Instead, you could use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [spread syntax for object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to build an object that keeps track of the occurrences of each item.

The object after `reduce()` looks like this:

```
{ a: "aaa", b: "bb", c: "ccc", d: "d", e: "ee" }
```

Once that object is built, all we have to do is create an array from the values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'c'];

let items = arr.reduce((acc,i) => acc[i] ? {...acc, [i]: acc[i]+i } : {...acc, [i]: i }, {});
let result = Object.values(items);

console.log(result);
```

---

**If you only want to join *adjacent* alike elements...**

The example below uses a slightly similar approach to the above, however *this* `reduce()` outputs a string. The logic is similar to your own example: if the previous item is the same, add it to a string. If it is *not*, separate it and keep going.

The result is something like this: `aaa|bb|ccc|d|ee`. To turn that into an array, we just need to do `split("|")`.

```js
const arr = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e'];

let result = arr
  .reduce((acc,i,idx,a) => (a[idx-1] === i || idx===0) ? acc+i : acc+"|"+i, "")
  .split("|");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const data = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e'];

const res = [...data.reduce((a,c)=>{
 return a.set(c, (a.get(c)||"") + c);
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(res);
```

#### Algo for strictly adjacent elements.

```js
const data = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e'];

const res = [];

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  const c = data[i];
  let str = c;
  for(let j = i + 1; j < data.length && c === data[j]; j++,i++){
      str += c;
  }
  res.push(str);
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution to join **adjacent elements**:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e'];

const resp = arr.reduce((a, e) => {
    if(a.length === 0) return a.concat(e);
    if(e === a[a.length - 1].split('').reverse()[0]) {
        a[a.length - 1] = a[a.length - 1].split('').concat(e).join('');
        return a;
    }
    return a.concat(e);
}, [])

console.log(resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
   function simplify(arr) {
        let current = arr[0];
        let final_arr = [];
        let accumulated = current;
        for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
            if (current === arr[i]) {
                accumulated += arr[i];
            } else {
                final_arr.push(accumulated)
                current = arr[i];
                accumulated = current;
            }
        }
        final_arr.push(accumulated);
        return final_arr;
    }
```

Comment: Why `current` and `accumulated`? Wouldn't just `accumulated` suffice?