# How to combine certain sections of an array in JS?

Tags: javascript

New to programming here... I am trying to combine certain sections of these strings within the array. I want to have all identical numbers grouped together in one string.

Here are the arrays I am working with:

let arr1 = [ '1', '1', '2', '2', '2' ]

let arr2 = [
'10', '10', '10',
'10', '34', '34',
'34', '34', '34',
'34', '92', '92'
]

I want the final result to be:

[11, 222]
[10101010, 343434343434, 9292]

I tried with the splice() method but it is just removing sections of my array.

Comment: *"together in one string"*; but your output has numbers, not strings. Do you really want *numbers* in your output? Or did you forget to put the quotes?

Comment: [JavaScript Join Identical Adjacent Elements in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54300223)

Answer (score 1):

If arr1 is sorted, you can do the following.

```js
let arr1 = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2'];

let result = [];
let currentNumber = "";

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    currentNumber += arr1[i];
    
    if (i === arr1.length - 1 || arr1[i] !== arr1[i + 1]) {
        result.push(parseInt(currentNumber));
        currentNumber = "";
    }
}

console.log(result)
```

If you want two results in a one string you can do as follows.

```js
function concatenateNumbers(arr) {
    let result = [];
    let currentNumber = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        currentNumber += arr[i];

        if (i === arr.length - 1 || arr[i] !== arr[i + 1]) {
            result.push(parseInt(currentNumber));
            currentNumber = "";
        }
    }

    return result;
}

let arr1 = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2'];
let arr2 = [ '10', '10', '10', '10', '34', '34', '34', '34', '34', '34', '92', '92' ];

let result1 = concatenateNumbers(arr1);
let result2 = concatenateNumbers(arr2);

let finalResult = `[${result1.join(', ')}] [${result2.join(', ')}]`;

console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: if not sorted, you can prolly get by with just using a map with key: base # and value: count and then expanding and pushing to array.